# Getting rid of popup boxes in web application

Tags: user-interface, web, popup

I am trying to resign a web application. Right now application is using multiple dialog boxes which seems to irritate users too much. Wondering is there is a way to eliminate pop up boxes and maybe use right panel for same? Any UX/UI examples where I can get some insight or an idea how to better design an interface?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions will vary widely depending on what your app is all about. Investing some time [reading about UI design principles](http://sixrevisions.com/category/user-interface/) can give you a powerful set of skills and tools to tackle these issues. If you've already gone down that road and you're ready to work on solutions, why not take a look at some of the design patterns and conventions built into frameworks such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), [Zurb Foundation](https://github.com/zurb/foundation), [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), and the like?

You may not need the whole set of features that come with these frameworks, but they include a good collection of well-tested UI patterns to draw inspiration from.

Generally speaking, pop-ups and modal dialogs interrupt users' flow. (And they can be tough to implement on small screeens.) Interruption is a good thing if you really need to get the user's attention. If that's not your goal, think about how else you can approach the problem.

- If your pop-up is for alerting your user, try something that appears inline on the page / UI.
- If your pop-up is for collecting user input, try a non-model popover (e.g. bootstrap's popover). Better yet, try to find ways to eliminate the need to collecting user input in the first place - ideal, if not always possible.

Bonus Round:

I've found some good UI and design pattern inspiration on [Little Big Details](http://littlebigdetails.com/) and [pttrns](http://pttrns.com/). There's no discussion about code on these sites, but it's useful to focus on the interaction patterns first and then think about specific ways to implement later. You'll also notice that a lot of the design patterns used for mobile / small screen applications can be helpful for designing UIs on larger screens; a small screen forces you to think about which parts of a UI are truly essential and which parts are just supporting details.

Also - this post on Smashing Magazine is a few years old now, but I remember finding a few gems in it: [40+ Helpful Resources On User Interface Design Patterns](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/)

I hope that helps!